# get the ruby's required module path(or the gem path)at run-time

Tags: ruby, module, require

Well, I googled this problem but I could not find one which could give it a clear explanation. 
  I want to know is there a general way for detecting the loaded module path at run time, which includes both ruby code and c extension code?
  If the $LOAD_PATH variable contains a lot of "Interface" modules which are defined in a lot of places, after calling "require 'Interface'", how can I tell which module is ruby using? 
  for example, both

```
/web/blogplus/lib
```

and

```
/web/blogplus/vendor
```

has a gem named "Interface", after launching the rails, if a controller implements the class like

```
class MyCtrl < Interface
end
```

then how can I know which module is MyCtrl is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection and use the `source_location` method.

```
Interface.public_methods().map{|m| Interface.public_method(m).source_location }.uniq
```